# generate_series for creating a list of months to get missing dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a view with monthly attendance (date is truncated by month):

```
----------------------------------------------------
| Student_ID    | Date             | Attendance    |
----------------------------------------------------
| 1             | 2017-01-01       | 4             |
| 1             | 2017-02-01       | 3             |
| 1             | 2017-04-01       | 4             |
| 1             | 2017-06-01       | 2             |
| 2             | 2017-03-01       | 5             |
| 2             | 2017-05-01       | 2             |
----------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, not every month appears for each ID, since this view counts and groups each date appearing in the actual attendance table. Nevertheless, I need every month to show up for each ID, even if with a 0.

```
----------------------------------------------------
| Student_ID    | Date             | Attendance    |
----------------------------------------------------
| 1             | 2017-01-01       | 4             |
| 1             | 2017-02-01       | 3             |
| 1             | 2017-03-01       | 0             |
| 1             | 2017-04-01       | 4             |
| 1             | 2017-05-01       | 0             |
| 1             | 2017-06-01       | 2             |
| 2             | 2017-01-01       | 0             |
| 2             | 2017-02-01       | 0             |
| 2             | 2017-03-01       | 5             |
| 1             | 2017-04-01       | 0             |
| 2             | 2017-05-01       | 2             |
| 1             | 2017-06-01       | 0             |
----------------------------------------------------
```

I tried unsuccesfully calling this view and doing a full join with

```
SELECT
    CAST(CAST('2017-01-01' AS DATE) + (interval '1' month * generate_series(0,11)) AS DATE) AS month,
    0 AS attendance
```

But it doesn't work, yet I feel somewhat close to the actual solution. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate all combinations of dates per student_id with a `cross join` and then `left join` the original table on that to get missing rows with `0` values.

```
select i.student_id,m.mth,coalesce(t.attendance,0)
from (select distinct student_id from tbl) i
cross join generate_series('2017-01-01'::date,'2017-12-01'::date, '1 MONTH') m(mth)
left join tbl t on t.student_id=i.student_id and t.dt=m.mth
```